# how do you write a specific branch to disk on post-receive git

Tags: git

I have a branch called "testing", and a post-receive hook that writes master to the live directory, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
env -i git reset --hard
```

I don't want to disrupt anything with the existing process that has been working okay for a long time, but when new changes are pushed to the testing branch I'd like git to write the branch's files to disk at /var/www/testing I've got this working using the following syntax:

```
git clone foo foo-copy
(cd foo-copy && git checkout branch)
```

but this operation is way too slow when pushing another commit on top of the testing branch and doesn't appear to overwrite files in the existing folder (though I think I might be wrong there)

tldr: how do I write a specific branch to a specific folder efficiently and with overwrite on post-receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I think

```
# one-time setup
mkdir -p /var/www/testing
git clone -s -b testing --single-branch myrepo /var/www/testing
```

And in `.git/hooks/post-receive` (in the main repo)

```
#!/bin/bash
while read old new refname; do
        if [[ $refname == refs/heads/testing ]]; then (
                eval unset ${!GIT_*}
                cd /var/www/testing
                git fetch
                git reset --hard origin/testing
        ); fi
done
```

will do the trick.  If you delete the testing branch in the main repo the deletion won't affect the clone, it'll just stop updating.

Comment: ah thank you, what does myrepo need to point to? the dir of the repo? or the .git folder specifically within the repo?

Comment: looks like it needs to be the repo folder as per the manual, thank you again :)